# Auto detecting one of two return types

Tags: typescript

I have a function called `isDone()` which returns the same information as one of two data structures (e.g., an array of hashes or a dictionary of hashes):

```
public async isDone() {
  this.startDelayedTasks();
  await Promise.all(this._tasks);
  const hadErrors = this._failed.length > 0 ? true : false;
  if (hadErrors) {
    throw new ParallelError(this);
  }
  return this._resultType === "hash"
    ? (this._results as IDictionary<T>)
    : hashToArray<IParallelArrayType<T>>(this._results) as IParallelArrayType<T>[];
}
```

where the IParallelArrayType is:

```
export interface IParallelArrayType<T> {
  name: string;
  value: T;
}
```

For consumers who ask for the array type they will likely want to run standard array-only functions like `map`, `filter`, or even just `length` but because the return type only *might* be an array it brings up the following error:

[image]

And of course the consumer can get around this by doing something like:

```
if(Array.isArray(results)) {
  expect(results.length).to.equal(4);
}
```

but it would be really nice if there was some way to avoid this burden on the consumer. I'm imagining something like a tagged union type and maybe using a Symbol for the property?

Seems like something like this might get me there but to really make it shine I'd want the consumers of the hash/dictionary return type to NOT have the Symbol key be part of their standard iterating tool `Object.keys(dictionary)`. Is this possible or am I getting to close to the runtime environment for this to work?

Comment: How does the consumer "ask for the array type" and how does it differ for asking for the dictionary type?  That call should return something that the consumer can use to avoid the subsequent check.

Comment: In the fluent interface there is a method called “returnAsArray()” (on phone atm so can’t post more verbosely)

Comment: This call sets the _resultType property you see in the isDone() method

Comment: What does `returnAsArray()` return?  If you're using method chaining it should return a new object whose type is "thing that returns array when you call `isDone()`", instead of changing the `_resultType` property of the existing object, which is essentially mutating its type, which TypeScript doesn't support.  Or even more straightforward, have `isDoneHash()` and `isDoneArray()` since apparently you do the transformation in that method anyway.

Comment: It’s a fluent api so it returns a reference to the object.

Comment: Ahh didn’t see your full comment at first. Yes I see what you’re talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just following up as an answer.  Your proposed idea would still require that the consumer perform some kind of check or assertion to convince the compiler that the returned value was an array as opposed to a dictionary.

The only way to relieve the consumer from this burden is to make sure that the fluent interface type *changes* after you call `returnAsArray()` to a version of the type which guarantees that `isDone()` returns an array.  Since TypeScript doesn't support the idea of mutating the type of an object, it's best if you return a different object.  Here's a sketch of the idea as code.  It's not using the same types or logic as yours (synchronous and manually setting results), but it should give the picture for how to implement it:

```
type Dictionary<T> = { [k: string]: T }
type EntryArray<T> = { k: string, v: T }[];
type ResultType<T> = {
  dict: Dictionary<T>;
  array: EntryArray<T>;
}
```

Here you have your two result types, as well as a mapping from the strings `"dict"` and `"array"` to the respective types.  Now we define our fluent class:

```
class FluentThing<T, R extends keyof ResultType<T>=keyof ResultType<T>> {
  readonly resultType: R;
  results: Dictionary<T> = {};
  constructor() {
    this.resultType = "dict" as R;
  }
  getResults(): ResultType<T>[R] {
    if (this.resultType === "dict") {
      return this.results;
    } else {
      return Object.keys(this.results).
        map(k => ({ k: k, v: this.results[k] }));
    }
  }
  addResult(k: string, v: T) {
    this.results[k] = v;
    return this;
  }
  someMethod() {
    return this;
  }
  wantArray(): FluentThing<T, "array"> {
    return Object.assign(
      new FluentThing(), this, { resultType: "array" }
    ) as FluentThing<T, "array">;
  };
  wantDict(): FluentThing<T, "dict"> {
    return Object.assign(
      new FluentThing(), this, { resultType: "dict" }
    ) as FluentThing<T, "dict">;
  }
}
```

Note how the `resultType` property is one of the strings `"array"` or `"dict"`, and it is `readonly` and not meant to change.  When you call `wantArray()` or `wantDict()`, a new `FluentThing` object is created with the same data as the current one except for the specified `resultType` property.  Also note how the `getResults()` method returns `ResultType<T>[R]`, which is `Dictionary<T>` if `R` is `"dict"`, or `EntryArray<T>` if `R` is `"array"`.

Let's use it:

```
const ft = new FluentThing<number>().addResult("a", 3).
  addResult("b", 4).someMethod();
const dict = ft.wantDict().someMethod().getResults();
// dict known to be Dictionary<number> at compile time,
// {a: 3, b: 4} at runtime
const arr = ft.wantArray().someMethod().someMethod().getResults();
// arr known to be EntryArray<number> at compile time,
// [{k: "a", v: 3}, {k: "b", v: 4}] at runtime.
```

This all works and the consumer can avoid an unnecessary check or assertion.  Yay!

---

Note at this point about the importance of returning a new object instead of mutating the existing one.  If you do mutate the `resultType` of the current object and just return `this` when `wantArray()` or `wantDict()` is called... you run the risk that the consumer will do something like the following:

```
const wantArray = ft.wantArray(); 
const wantDict = ft.wantDict();
const shouldBeArray = wantArray.getResults();
```

The contract of `FluentThing` declares that `shouldBeArray` will be an array, but if you just have a single `FluentThing` object and mutate its `resultType` whenever `wantXXX()` is called, it will not be, since `wantDict()` was called on it after `wantArray()`.  Only you know if your consumer is likely to hold onto intermediate values of your fluent interface and try to reuse them.  If not, then maybe mutation will work for you despite this issue.

---

Also note that I'm not sure why you make the consumer specify that they want the results as an array or as a dictionary before actually getting the results.  It is more straightforward from both the consumer's point of view and from the type system point of view if this decision is delayed until the data is actually returned to the consumer:

```
type Dictionary<T> = { [k: string]: T }
type EntryArray<T> = { k: string, v: T }[];

class FluentThing<T> {
  results: Dictionary<T> = {};
  getResultsAsDictionary(): Dictionary<T> {
    return this.results;
  }
  getResultsAsArray(): EntryArray<T> {
    const resultsDict = this.getResultsAsDictionary();
    return Object.keys(resultsDict).map(k => ({ k: k, v: resultsDict[k] }));
  }
  addResult(k: string, v: T) {
    this.results[k] = v;
    return this;
  }
  someMethod() {
    return this;
  }
}

const ft = new FluentThing<number>().addResult("a", 3).
  addResult("b", 4).someMethod();
const dict = ft.someMethod().getResultsAsDictionary();
const arr = ft.someMethod().someMethod().getResultsAsArray();
```

This acts nearly identically to the previous version, except that everything is simpler.  Something like that could be preferable, unless your use case requires that the consumer specify the desired result format early for some reason I don't see.

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Very thorough answer and very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript has type unions which can also be applied to methods. You can use the below concept to make your function return one of the two types that a user might be asking for.

```
class Foo {
    test1: string = ' test value';
    test2: number = 2;
    bar(testArg: string | number): string | number {
        return testArg;
    };
}

let foo = new Foo();
let output1 = foo.bar(foo.test1);
let output2 = foo.bar(foo.test2);
console.log(output1); //test value
console.log(output2); //2
```